# Mongoose typeError with custom Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to use `discountSchema` as a type. But I'm getting this error:

```
throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +
      ^
TypeError: Undefined type at `discount`
```

but if I transform to type `array`:

```
    discount: {
        type: [discountSchema],
        default:{}
    }
```

it works.

How can I use complex type in mongoose as this?
Am I using this model in a wrong way? How can I model this object like this?

```js
var discountSchema = new Schema({
    type: {type: String,default:'' },
    quantity: {type: Number,default:0 },
    value: {type: Number,default:0 }
});
var objectEncomendaPropertiesSchema = {
    recheios:{
        type:[String],
        default: [],
        select: true
    },
    availableEncomenda: {
        type: Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    discount: {
        type: discountSchema,
        default:{}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cant't set** `embedded documents` stored as single property in mongoose, they are **always stored in arrays**.

The closest thing to this behaviour is setting your property to an `ObjectId` with a `ref` and using the `populate` method to fetch it.
Take a look [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to see how this approach works.

---

Check out embedded documents [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2689) on GitHub requesting the behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks for those links! yep, I just can't models the way I want. I think I gonna use `Mixed` type

Comment: You are welcome, I don't like `mixed` type because mongoose loses the ability to auto detect and save changes in those properties. Why not use an array and assume that you will always have 1 or 0 elements within it?

Comment: yeah I'm thinking on this possibility now that you mentioned. Thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to create two Schemas then wire them up?

```
var discountSchema = new Schema({
    type: {type: String,default:'' },
    quantity: {type: Number,default:0 },
    value: {type: Number,default:0 }
});

mongoose.model('Discount', discountSchema);

var objectEncomendaPropertiesSchema = new Schema({
    recheios:{
        type: String,
        default: '',
        select: true
    },
    availableEncomenda: {
        type: Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    discount: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Discount'
    }
})

mongoose.model('objectEncomendaProperties', objectEncomendaPropertiesSchema);
```

I reference the discount in the second schema to reference to the first schema by the ObjectId 
It will fetch the properties in the Discount model as a discount property in the second Schema.